# Некорректное разрешение экрана в браузере на мобилках

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile-web

```
document.write('Display size: <b>' + window.screen.width + '×' + window.screen.height + ' px.</b><br>');
document.write('Browser size: <b>' + window.innerWidth + '×' + window.innerHeight + ' px.</b><br>');
document.write('Avail size: <b>' + window.screen.availWidth + '×' + window.screen.availHeight + ' px.</b><br>');
```

Проверяю на нескольких устройствах - на некоторых работает нормально, на некоторых нет. Почему в некоторых случаях разрешение ниже реального?

Desktop - всё правильно.

Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 выдаёт 1280*800, верно.

Samsung A5(2017) выдаёт 640*360, но реальное разрешение 1920*1080.

iPad 4 выдаёт 1024*768, но реальное разрешение 2048*1536.

iPhone 5 SE выдаёт 568*320, но реальное разрешение 1136*640.

Comment: Используйте `@media` запросы.

Comment: Даже примерно не представляю, как их использовать. [Описал контекст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755919/Подгонка-разрешения-в-браузере-на-мобилках) задачи, в котором задавался данным вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

[Подсказали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242086/how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-with-javascript/2242100#2242100), что нужно умножать на `devicePixelRatio`, т.е. должно быть `window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio` и `window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio`

Answer (score 1):

Вроде должен помочь:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Ну и для `height` подобный.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде помогло, сейчас потестирую «в бою».

Comment: [Описал контекст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755919/Подгонка-разрешения-в-браузере-на-мобилках) задачи, в котором задавался вопросом разрешения экрана. Гляньте пожалуйста, если есть возможность.