# Подгонка разрешения в браузере на мобилках

Tags: javascript, android, ios, разработка-игр, mobile-web

Cтолкнулся с проблемой отображения HTML5 игр, сделанных на GameMaker Studio, на мобильных устройствах (iOS и Android). Ремарка: с HTML/CSS и еже с ними почти не сталкивался, опыта никакого.

Для примера, игра в 960*640. Взял такое изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске на телефоне вижу такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На экран также выводится разрешение браузера, которое возвращает движок. Как видно, оно в три раза меньше реального разрешения. Естественно, первым делом подумал, что ошибка в движке. Проверил, что возвращает непосредственно браузер - значения были те же самые. Задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755834/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85/755840) и [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/755841/12556) histrionis'а натолкнул на мысль, что `viewport` как-то может помочь, ибо неизвестно сколько времени пройдёт, пока разработчики движка исправят проблему (если исправят вообще).

Заглянул в `index.html`, генерируемый движком, там стоит строка

```
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Как понял, именно из-за этого отключается масштабирование канваса с игрой.

Так как не знаком с этой темой, наугад потыкал разные значения, например

```
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height" />
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=960, height=640" />
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=640, height=960" />
```

и др.

Однако к желаемому результату это не привело (но частичные улучшения бывали).

Есть ли какая-нибудь магия, которая приведёт к нормальной работе всего этого?

P.S. Если поможет:

Сам `index.html` можно глянуть [здесь](https://pastebin.com/QrGzz0C3)

Скомпилированный проект [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cujv7d9szn3lz7u/example.zip?dl=0) (как понимаю, с локалки не работает)

P.P.S. По браузерам ориентируюсь на Chrome и Samsung Internet для Android и Safari с Chrome на iOS.

**upd:** При использовании, например, `<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`, я вижу всё изображение, но его вертикальное разрешение ниже, чем должно быть. Например, 960*480 (экран 1920*1080) в ландшафтном режиме. Конечно же, игра в этом случае выглядит ужасно (размытость, нечитаемые мелкие тексты и т.п). В этом же случае при повороте в портретный режим браузер выдаёт разрешение 960*1494. Тогда изображение выглядит отлично, но оно слишком мелкое - занимает чуть больше одной трети экрана (из-за того, что ориентации противоположные). Т.е. мне в первую очередь нужно, чтобы в ландшафтном режиме высота браузера не была меньше высоты канваса игры.

**upd2:** С помощью Vasiliy Rusin найдено решение, которое решило проблему на Android (при этом браузер должен запрашивать ПК версию сайта, а не мобильную). На iOS по-прежнему отображается в очень низком разрешении.

Comment: Размер одного CSS-пикселя равен размеру двух или трёх реальных пикселей (а на некоторых устройствах разница вообще не целое число), смотрите `window.devicePixelRatio`

Comment: Да, про `devicePixelRatio` я уже знаю (есть по ссылке в вопросе), но не представляю, как его подставить сюда.

Comment: Может быть дело в строке `<canvas id="canvas" width="960" height="640">` ?

Comment: @histrionis это собственно сам канвас, на котором игра. Что с ним можно попробовать сделать, чтобы исправить ситуацию? Его размер я могу менять в самой игре, но я ограничен теми `browser_width` и `browser_height`, которые выдаёт движок - а они, как уже писал, меньшего размера. Если бы браузер выдавал верный размер экрана (при масштабе 1:1), то это бы решило проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте `<canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%">`

Comment: @histrionis Так получается совсем низкое разрешение - на одну надпись приходится пара пикселей по высоте.

Comment: Но сам блок по высоте и ширине подгоняется? Если да, то надписи придется подгонять отдельно (Делать стиль адаптивным), но это даже звучит как костыль. Лучше обратиться к тематическим форумам, наверняка кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Comment: @histrionis Если я, например, укажу `initial-scale=0.3`, то на девайсе, с которого скриншот, всё становится отлично. Но на других девайсах нужно подставлять другое значение - как это можно сделать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69975/discussion-between-histrionis-and-dmi7ry).

Comment: А что вам в итоге нужно то? Что бы `canvas` растягивался на весь экран? Или что бы он всегда был внутри экрана но с тем же соотношением?

Comment: @VasiliyRusin Нужно чтобы канвас был вписан в экран с сохранением соотношения сторон. Однако это можно делать даже непосредственно в коде игры. Проблема в том, этот канвас рисуется с более низким разрешением, из-за чего сильно теряется качество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не следует изменять

```
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Эта строка делает ровно то что вам нужно. Вы не учитываете довольно много факторов.

1. Размер экрана **не равен** размеру окна браузера. У вас есть интерфейс который отнимает определенное место.
2. Разрешение экрана **не равно** размеру экрана *(особенно на телефонах)*. На один виртуальный пиксель приходится несколько пикселей физических. Вы множите получить множитель через `window.devicePixelRatio`
3. Размер вашего холста сейчас указан в коде и происходит именно то что вы ожидаете *(так думает браузер)*. А именно, при размере браузерного окна 640 x 232. Размер холста все еще 960 x 640.
4. У браузеров есть **баг** *(Так думает большинство программистов, но на самом деле они не правы)*. При изменении ориентации размеры `screen.width` и `screen.height` не изменяются. Хотя они и не должны, ведь размер самого экрана остается прежним.

Зная все это мы можем написать следующий код:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

function canvas_resize(){
    canvas.width = 960 * window.devicePixelRatio;
    canvas.height = 640 * window.devicePixelRatio;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    canvas_resize();
})

window.addEventListener("orientationchange", canvas_resize);

// Скорее всего это уже избыточно но лучше перестраховаться.
window.addEventListener("resize", canvas_resize);
```

Код довольно прост мы изменяем размеры `canvas`. При загрузке страницы, и в дальнейшем при каждом перевороте устройства или изменении размера экрана.

Обратите внимание что при размере окна браузера в 960x640

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="960" height="640">
```

не будет равно

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Это связано с тем что `width="100%" height="100%"` в данном случае изменят размер **DOM элемента `canvas`, а не самого холста**. По умолчанию размер холста например в Chromium (Chromium, Google Chrome, Opera, Yandex.Browser) будет 300x150 пикселей.

так же обратите внимание что в CSS должны быть следующие стили, если их еще нет:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
canvas{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 1. Размером интерфейса я пренебрегаю для упрощения обсуждения, так как а) где возможно, будет использоваться полноэкранный режим и б) в большинстве случаев даже за вычетом интерфейса канвас должен влезать без уменьшения. 2. Знаю, вопрос содержит [ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755834/Некорректное-разрешение-экрана-в-браузере-на-мобилках/755840). 4. innerWidth/innerHeight выдают виртуальное разрешение, из-за чего я получаю в три раза уменьшенное изображение, растянутое затем на 1920*1080. Результат ужасен, конечно же. (+сам канвас я могу масштабировать из игры)

Comment: Оу в canvas_resize ошибочка. Тогда вам нужно изменить `canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerWidth * (2/3);` на `canvas.width = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio; canvas.height = window.innerWidth * (2/3) * devicePixelRatio;` Тогда вы получаете реальный размер экрана по ширине и сохранение пропорций по высоте. Попробуйте, а я пока что исправлю ответ.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что единственный способ - увеличивать размер канваса в соответствии с `devicePixelRatio` (а браузер автоматом его уменьшит на то же самое значение при рисовании)? Попробовал - работает частично. Подробнее: 1. После загрузки разрешение низкое, пока не повернёшь телефон. 2. В настроках браузера должно быть выбрано «запрашивать версию для ПК», иначе разрешение всегда низкое. Как избежать? 3. На iOS не работает - всё время в низком разрешении.

Comment: Браузер ничего не уменьшит. `сanvas.width = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;` это ширина в соответствии с **реальным** разрешением экрана.

Comment: @Dmi7ry 1 очень странно, по идеи `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { canvas_resize(); })` выполняется сразу после загрузки DOM, соответственно и ресайз должен происходить сразу же. Возможно это проблема конкретного браузера. Или у вас не обновился кеш, и все езе используется старый код, рекомендую попробовать запустить в инкогнито.

Comment: 2. В настроках браузера должно быть выбрано «запрашивать версию для ПК», иначе разрешение всегда низкое. Как избежать?

Полагаю что никак, скорее всего режим телефона уменьшает экран для увеличения производительности.  Этот вопрос вам лучше задать отдельно.

Comment: 3. Давайте убьем двух зайцев. Выведите `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { alert(window.devicePixelRatio) })` и на iOS тоже. Если выведется узнаете нет ли проблем со старым кешем и какие значения находятся в devicePixelRatio на iOS.

Comment: 2. Хорошо, спасибо. 1. Угу, я понимаю, что это странно. Более того, если воткнуть для проверки alert, то он срабатывает. Но разрешение всё равно низкое. Проверяю в 4 браузерах (в вопросе указано, какие). При каждом изменении заливаю на хост в новую папку - как раз, чтобы исключить проблемы с кешированием. Наверное это отвечает и на третий пункт. Ratio 3 на Android и 2 на iOS.

Comment: @Dmi7ry, Меня это очень заинтересовало, если у Вас есть время попробовать разобраться то можем пойти в чат.

Comment: @Dmi7ry, Проверьте размеры `canvas` после инициализации. `canvas.width = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio; canvas.height = window.innerWidth * (2/3) * devicePixelRatio; alert(canvas.width); alert(canvas.height)`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69996/discussion-between-dmi7ry-and-vasiliy-rusin).

Answer (score 1):

Пиксель в данном контексте понятие относительное, на разных устройствах свой так называемые `scale`: [**Подробнее.**](https://mydevice.io/devices/)

Решается крайне просто, изменение `viewport`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = yes">
```

Если подробнее разобраться желаете - [**справка**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).

***Пример*** вычисления высоты и ширины разрешения на устройстве через `window.devicePixelRatio`:

```js
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var mw = screen.width * ratio;
var mh = screen.height * ratio;
alert(screen.width);
alert(screen.height);
alert(mw);
alert(mh);
```

Зная `devicePixelRatio`, можно изменить `viewport`:

```
$.mobile.media("screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: [yourDevicePixelRation])");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Никита. Про scale я знаю. К сожалению, включение `user-scalable` не меняет ровным словом ничего в моём случае (движок перехватывает пользовательский ввод, что логично, иначе невозможно было бы играть). Можно ли как-то при загрузке устанавливать `initial-scale`, чтобы он автоматом рассчитывался в зависимости от pixel ratio устройства? Типа `initial-scale = 1/pixel-ratio` (не знаю, можно ли подставить переменную туда). Может через JS как-нибудь?

Comment: @Dmi7ry написал пример через js, посмотрите.